# Why the sequence of the stream is different to the original file?

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to test the simple flink code as below. 
The original dataset's sequence is `1,2,3,4`.

After reading the file, the sequence of the stream is `1,4,2,3'. Moreover, the order is different whenever I tested it.

How to fix the order of the input dataset as same to the original context?

Below is my simpel code.

```
   DataStreamSource<Integer> integerDataStreamSource = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4);
   integerDataStreamSource.print();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering of the output stream is non-deterministic because the print sink is running in parallel, and these parallel instances are racing against each other. If you want to prevent this, you can set the parallelism of either the entire job, or of the print sink operator, to one.

```java
env.setParallelism(1);
DataStreamSource<Integer> integerDataStreamSource = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4);
integerDataStreamSource.print();
```